# What does the `document.write` do in this js snippet?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, domdocument

The codes looks like this

```
  var addScript = function(path, server){
    server = server || scriptConfig.server;
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + server + path +'"></script>');
  };

  if (scriptConfig.autoLoadDependencies) {
    addScript("/javascripts/webtoolkit.base64.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/swfobject.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/underscore/underscore.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Loader.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/API.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Binder.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/ControlBar.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/DataStore.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Filters.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/JSON.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Model.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Parser.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Scope.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Server.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Users.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Validators.js");
    addScript("/javascripts/nglr/Widgets.js");
  } else {
    addScript("/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com");
    addScript("/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com");
    addScript("/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com");
  }
```

As noted in [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write),

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling
>   document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   document.open which will clear the document.

`document.write` will clear the whole document. If so, won't the first call of `addScript` clear the whole page? Does that mean it could load these js file but the whole HTML DOM will be lost?

As I understand, a snippet like this **doesn't seem useful if it will clear the whole document**.... am I right?

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: What I see here is addScript just loads some scripts from server with specified path.

Comment: No, it won't. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is in a page like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>//that stuff</script>
    </head>
....
```

In this case, the document has not yet been "closed", as it is still in the process of loading. Hence, it shouldn't clear the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

If this code is wrapped by `<script></script>`, then it will append the code right after the `<script></script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, When addScript function will call, Then document.write just write your string inside document.write method in your document. Now you can use this script.